# Contao intermittent 500 error

Tags: php, .htaccess, contao, http-status-code-500

Contao 3.5.9

I am getting a 500 server error in my contao website. This occurs intermitently on every page.
error_log shows the following:

> xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [29/Apr/2016:11:08:39 +0000] "GET /news-insight/news.html HTTP/1.1" 500 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.112 Safari/537.36"

PHP log shows nothing.

I am using the default htaccess file

Has anyone come across this before? How can it be fixed?

Comment: You can give us more information, what is your OS? which version of PHP you are using? maybe look at `system/logs/error.log` in your application root and search for a corresponding entry.

Comment: Also try to enable the `coreOnlyMode` by putting `$GLOBALS['TL_CONFIG']['coreOnlyMode'] = true;` in your `/system/config/localconfig.php` and then test again. If the error does not happen again, an extension is probably at fault.